# Integrating slow UI tests into CI deployment pipeline

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, teamcity, integration-testing

We use a fairly standard CI deployment pipeline in Teamcity to package our application.  We started out with the following pipeline.  Each of the steps below represent a gate that the build must pass in order to advance to the next step:

1. Compile
2. Unit Tests
3. Back-end component integration tests
4. Front-end acceptance tests (Selenium based)
5. Package

This worked alright in the beginning of the project when the front-end test suite was small and relatively quick ( <2 mins).  However, as the suite grew in size and length (15:00 minutes and growing), firing it off on every check-in quickly became untenable.  We have since removed the suite from our main pipeline and kick it off four times daily on an independent pipeline:

1. Compile
2. Unit Tests
3. Back-end component integration tests
4. Package

The problem with this approach is clear, in that it is quite likely a build will make it all the way to the package stage even though it caused regressions in the front-end test suite.   I suppose I could invalidate an already created package if the front-end test suite fails, but this seems clunky.  We've looked at optimizing the test suite further but I think that's a dead end unless we can run the tests in parallel, something which TeamCity doesn't support.

Suggestions/critiques welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what development platform you are working here, but I see two general options.

1. Use selenium grid or something like testNG
2. Leverage any teamcity build agents you have, and section up tests to be run in parallel on an array of these agents. I have in the past had dedicated build agents running tests, but even so this method will eventually fall over if your test sets increase too much in size.

You should be aiming to reduce the amount of testing you do directly through the UI. Look at how putting more emphasis on testing code further down the stack can reduce your direct UI test burden. In a recent project we refactored the javascript in our app to make it testable. These faster running tests meant that we could remove a large amount of our slower running webdriver tests. Its a bit of an investment in time and effort, but its causes much less pain than your current situation.

Scheduled builds should be avoided where possible as, like you mentioned, you could end up with packaged software that has bundled defects, plus the feedback time increases massively.